# Machine Check Exception

Tags: hardware

I am running Ubuntu Server on a Dell PowerEdge server. I found following the log entry from the server `dmesg`. The Dell Pro Support requested to run Dell's DSET diagnostics. They found no hardware problems reported by DSET and the support person said that this log message is a reporting problem in Ubuntu. Can this be a software bug in Ubuntu?

Thanks

Sami

```
[1457944.748752] sbridge: HANDLING MCE MEMORY ERROR<br>
[1457944.748761] CPU 1: Machine Check Exception: 0 Bank 10: 8c000046000800c1<br>
[1457944.748763] TSC 0 ADDR 2df41c3000 MISC 900080008000c8c PROCESSOR 0:306e4 TIME 1395313612 SOCKET 1 APIC 20<br>
[1457945.659958] EDAC MC1: 1 CE memory scrubbing error on CPU_SrcID#1_Channel#1_DIMM#0 (channel:1 slot:0 page:0x2df41c3 offset:0x0 grain:32 syndrome:0x0 -  area:DRAM err_code:0008:00c1 socket:1 channel_mask:1 rank:0)<br>
```

Comment: Please provide details on hardware (see my answer for things you can check)

Answer (score 2):

I have an update to this issue. Finally the problem was found and the cause was a faulty DIMM module. Interestingly none of Dell diagnostics tests revealed this problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to Dell, the EDAC software actually hides the error from Dell's own hardware tools. You have to blacklist the module to get it to pass through.

http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN283389/EN/

Answer (score 1):

Probably hardware related bug.

- [Fedora bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=875194#c8). From comments a method in diagnosing:

> After a lot of diagnostics and working with vendor support, it appears
>   this is almost certainly a hardware problem with some versions of
>   X9DR3-LN4+ motherboards.
>
> The problem boards report "REV:1.10" as their Version in 'dmidecode -t baseboard'.
>
> At our site, older boards with a Version of "0123456789" have not produced the errors, and we are replacing the faulty boards with newer
>   boards of the same model, Version "REV:1.20A".
>
> On the faulty motherboards, the errors seems to manifest mostly with the higher speed 2.90 GHz E5-2690 processors and full (24 RDIMMM)
>   RAM configs, but we have been able to reproduce it with fewer RDIMMs.
>
> FWIW, memtester did not generate the errors; the method i hit upon was just to exercise the buffer cache.  So on a system with 384 GB of RAM, i'd put about 400 GB of data in a local file system mounted at `/scratch`, and do:
>
> ```
> while true ; tar cf - /scratch | cat - >/dev/null ; done
> ```
>
> (In my experiments, writing to /dev/null from tar would not work... the "cat - >/dev/null" was required.)  While this is running, you can check the error counts with this:
>
> ```
> cat /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc?/ce*count
> ```
>
> The observed Error rate was usually at least one MCE error per hour

- Some more possible checks you can perform: [I'm getting MCE (Machine Check Exception) errors, what does this mean?](http://www.advancedclustering.com/faq/im-getting-mce-machine-check-exception-errors-what-does-this-mean.html)

.